# R: Get position of first backreference in regex match

Tags: r, regex, backreference

I'm using R. I have a regular expression with a capturing group. I'd like to find the position and length of the first backreference (`\\1`) in the first matching substring.

For example, let's say the regex is `b(a+)b` and the string is `bbaaab`; the first matching substring is `baaab` starting at position 2, the starting position of the first backreference is 3, and the length of the first backreference is 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll show how to do it by building on the example in the question.

If you do `regexpr("b(a+)b", "bbaaab", perl = TRUE)` you get

```
[1] 2
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 5
attr(,"useBytes")
[1] TRUE
attr(,"capture.start")

[1,] 3
attr(,"capture.length")

[1,] 3
attr(,"capture.names")
[1] ""
```

So if you want to get the start of the first backreference, you do `attr(regexpr("b(a+)b", "bbaaab", perl = TRUE), 'capture.start')[1]`, and if you want to get its length you do `attr(regexpr("b(a+)b", "bbaaab", perl = TRUE), 'capture.length')[1]`. You can easily generalize this to get the position and length of the nth backreference / capturing group.

Comment: Yes, however it's better to run the regex only once.